# Animated plot required to leave behind trace

Tags: plotting

```
Animate[Plot[2 x a - a^2, {x, -2, 2}], {a, -2, 2}, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

During run I need the output to display two things

1. Leave a trace of the straight line tangent on a default increment of animation parameter `a`.
2. Prevent the axes from quivering (not steady) while axes are scaled for each plot.

By specifying fixed range/domain limits can I effectively fix the 2nd problems?

EDIT1:

```
a = 1; plt1 = Plot[2 x a - a^2, {x, -2, 2}];
a = .5; plt2 = Plot[2 x a - a^2, {x, -2, 2}];
a = -.5; plt3 = Plot[2 x a - a^2, {x, -2, 2}];
a = -1; plt4 = Plot[2 x a - a^2, {x, -2, 2}];
Show[{plt1, plt2, plt3, plt4}]
```

EDIT2:

BTW, it is solution of Clairaut's Differential equation

$$ y = 2p-p^2,\, p= \frac{dy}{dx}, $$

with singular solution

$$y=x^2 $$

which can be seen here.

Comment: Ad 2) just add `PlotRange -> {-10, 5}` (or any plot range that looks appealing to you) in the `Plot`.

Comment: Thanks, Some of fleeting lines 1) need also to be captured.

Comment: Do you know how to make a static plot showing the set of tangents you want to see in the animation? If you do, then it's not hard to animate what you want. If not, you should work on the static plot first. When you done that  come back with any questions about converted it an animation.

Comment: What do you mean by "leaving behind a trace"? Is this something you to do or is it something you want to suppress? You need to be clearer.

Comment: Yes. I choose a parameter value, plot to that value calling it plot1, likewise choose a second parameter labelled plot2 .... and Show them all. kind of nasty.

Comment: I want it be shown, I want to actually see *the envelope* in a single frame, But not a dynamic moving line.

Comment: m_goldberg edited as above

Comment: @Narasimham Regarding your edit: does not work because of the misplaced closing bracket `]` in the third line.

Comment: While the question may have been asked in a somewhat confusing manner,  considering the (excellent) answers here I see absolutely no reason to close the question.

Comment: Since editing is still possible for the benefit of those who may be following the question/answer, please suggest how better to ask the question with less confusion or more clarity. I am pleased with both the instant answers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
plots = Table[
   Plot[2 x a - a^2, {x, -2, 2}, Filling -> Axis, 
    PlotRange -> {-5, 3}], {a, -1, 1, 0.1}];

frames = FoldList[Show, First @ plots, Rest @ plots];
  (* or simply *)
frames = FoldList[Show, plots] (* thanks: Simon Woods *)

ListAnimate[frames, AnimationRate -> 2]
```

[image]

---

`Exported` with

```
Export["plot.gif", frames, "DisplayDurations" -> 1/2]
```

Comment: In recent versions you can use `frames = FoldList[Show, plots]`

Answer (score 16):

This approach is slightly more complicated than corey979's but has the advantage that number of ghost lines is independent from the number of `a` you want to use (in other words, the animation below is "continuous", not step by step).

```
aMax = 4; (* max value of a *)
n = 30; (* number of ghost lines *)
f[x_, a_] = 2 x a - a^2;
lines = Table[Line[{{-aMax, f[-aMax, a]}, {aMax, f[aMax, a]}}], {a, 
    Subdivide[-aMax, aMax, n]}];
showLines[a_] := Block[{},
  pos = Position[Subdivide[-aMax, aMax, n], _?(# < a &)];
  If[Length@pos > 0, Graphics[{Lighter[Blue, .4], lines[[;; Last@Last@pos]]}], 
   Graphics[]]]
list = Table[ Show[Plot[2 x a - a^2, {x, -aMax, aMax}, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-10, 7}}, 
     PlotStyle -> Darker[Blue, .5]], showLines[a], 
    Frame -> True], {a, -aMax, aMax, 0.1}];
```

[image]

Comment: Exporting shown @corey979

Comment: @Narasimham I know this but I wanted to keep the `Manipulate` frame :)

Comment: See [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/ImportAndExportAnimations.html), although - works for .avi, doesn't work for .gif.

Comment: @corey979 Yes I've seen this, but when converting the `avi` to `gif` rendered strange colors... Nevermind, I exported without the frame :)

Answer (score 8):

My bid for your consideration.  First I would simplify the `Plot` to a single `Line` segment, then abstract this to a function:

```
(* s = start; i = increment *)

fn[s_, i_][f_] := Line @ Table[{{-2, -4 a - a^2}, {2, 4 a - a^2}}, {a, s, f, i}]
```

From there I can animate smoothly as follows:

```
Animate[
  Graphics[{{LightGray, fn[-2, 0.2][a]}, fn[a, 1][a]}
   , PlotRange -> {-5, 3}
   , AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio
   , Axes -> True
  ]
  , {a, -2, 2}
  , AnimationRate -> 1
  , RefreshRate -> 60
  , DisplayAllSteps -> True
]
```

Animation:

[image]

Comment: Small detail: for the animation, I changed the order in `Graphics` so that the main line is on top.

Comment: @anderstood Thanks for the .GIF, and the note on order.  I'll correct that in the code.

Comment: I'm too lazy to write an answer, so: `InfiniteLine[{0, -a^2}, {1, 2 a}]` works well for depicting the lines, and it is easy to see how it was derived from the original equation of the line.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for the suggestion.  It's good to see you posting again, by the way. :-)

Comment: Yeah, it's great to be back; I was sick for most of my hiatus, so being able to post here again is nice.

Comment: @J.M. I am sorry to hear that!  Are you OK now?

Comment: Well, slightly better than last month, at least. It seems a lot of nice stuff only shows up when I'm on a break... :P

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The traces seem to contrast more without "LightGray".